# Why is child component not receiving updated value from parent in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When an arrow is clicked the Cart Item View needs to expand that particular view and collapse any others currently expanded.  The item id of that product is passed to the parent component to update which view is to be expanded (active).  Although, the id is being passed and set on the expandedItem property in the reducer this does not get updated to the child component (even though it's being passed as prop on the child component).  When the child component is re-evaluated at the end the expandedViewItem is still 0, which is it's default value.  Does anyone know how to get the child component to receive the updated expandedItem value?  Why is it still 0??

PLEASE watch the video I made debugging this issue:  https://youtu.be/qEgxqAyWDpY

Here is where the value is evaluated in the **child component**:

```
render () {

const isExpanded = product.id === this.props.expandedViewId;
```

Here is the entire child component class:

```
export default class CartProductItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {showCounter: false};
    }

    expandCartProductItem(id) {
        this.props.onExpandClick(id); 
        this.setState(this.state);
    }

    updateDisplay = (nextProps) => {
        // Null check is needed here as 0 is a valid value
        if (nextProps.activeIndex !== null && nextProps.activeIndex === this.props.index) {
            this.setState({
                showCounter: !this.state.showCounter
            });
        } else if (nextProps.activeIndex !== null && nextProps.activeIndex !== this.props.index) {
            this.setState({
                showCounter: false
            });
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log('nextProps: ', nextProps)
    }

    render() {
        const serverUrl = getServerAddress();
        const {product} = this.props;
        const price = product.iogmodPrice ? product.iogmodPrice : product.price;

        const isExpanded = product.id === this.props.expandedViewId;

        const imageSrc = product.imageName
            ? 'https://b2b.martinsmart.com/productimages/'+ product.imageName.replace("Original", "Thumbnail")
            : serverUrl + '/b2b/resources/images/nophoto.gif';

        return (
            <View style={styles.pContainer}>
                <CartProduct
                    imageName={imageSrc}
                    name={product.description}
                    itemNum={product.id}
                    price={price}
                    pack={product.pack}
                    averageWeight={product.averageWeight}
                    cases={product.order_count}
                />

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={() => this.expandCartProductItem(product.id)}>
                    {isExpanded ? <LineIcon name="arrow-up" style={styles.arrowIcon} /> : <LineIcon name="arrow-down" style={styles.arrowIcon} />}
                </TouchableOpacity>

                {isExpanded &&
                    <ExpandHeightView height={70}>
                        <View style={styles.counterContainerView}>
                            <QuantityCounter style={{width: '100%'}} product={product} />
                        </View>
                    </ExpandHeightView>
                }
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the **parent component** function that passes the id to the action and the initial const declarations in the render:

```
expandAndCollapseItems = (id) => {
    this.props.dispatch(collapseCartItemViews(id));
}

render() {
    const {isLoading, displayDetails, sortCasesAsc, details, items, expandedItem} = this.props.orderInfo;
```

Here is the child component in the parent component where the **expandedItem** variable is being passed into it:

```
<FlatList 
    data={items}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
    renderItem={({item}) => <CartProductItem product={item} expandedViewId={expandedItem} onExpandClick={(id) => this.expandAndCollapseItems(id)} />}
/>
```

Finally, here is the reducer function updates the app state:

```
    case types.SET_EXPANDED_STATE:
        const id = action.id;

        return {
            ...state,
            expandedItem: id
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the code for your `CartProductItem`, more specifically how it uses the `onExpandClick` prop that it's given

Comment: Not sure why it's coming out 0, but if you're using redux you can always just grab that value directly in the CartProductItem instead of passing it down.

Comment: @PatNeedham I have updated my question to include the entire CartProductItem class code.

Comment: @MattAft How do I grab the value direclty from CartProductItem when I'm not using mapStateToProps (connect)?

Comment: can you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on https://codesandbox.io/s/new?

Comment: By using mapStateToProps lol, just grab the expandedItem id from the redux store and everything else should work the same as if you were passing it down

Comment: @MattAft  ahh ok true lol.  It worked so you can go ahead and make an official answer and I'll give you the points ;)

Comment: glad to hear it worked! just posted an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using redux, you can just grab the expanded item id from the redux store in the child instead of passing it down from the parent.